# Passing info of marked property into custom attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, custom-attributes, system.reflection

I am trying to create a custom attribute, in which an argument is the name of a property of the property the attribute is used on.

**I guess that did not make much sense when typed out, so here's an example of what I am trying to do:**

```
[Test(x => x.Paws)]
public Dog Dog { get; set; }
```

As you see, I have used the attribute on **Dog**, and use a lambda expression to pass the **paws** property of dog to the constructor of the attribute.

Is this possible?
The best I have come up with so far is the following:

```
[Test(nameof(Dog.Paws)]
public Dog Dog { get; set; }
```

The reason why this solution is not optimal is due to the fact that there is no type checking (I could write **nameof(Cat.Tail)** as well.

So my question is; is this possible? And if so, how would one do it?

Comment: No, you can't use a lambda expression in an attribute. I would just use `nameof` and then add a unit test to make sure that all the attribute values are appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that can't be done. Attributes only accept a select few types as parameters:

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkattributestutorialanchor1

> - Primitive types (bool, byte, char, int, etc...)
> - Strings
> - Types (`System.Type`)
> - enums
> - object
> - one dimensional arrays

Your apporach using `nameof()` is a good one, though. Keep in mind you can use `typeof()` as well!

Comment: That's what I feared.
Oh well, I'll use nameof instead.